# Valor inicial en oi-select

Tags: angularjs, select

Tengo el siguiente select:

```
<span>Primer aspecto critico <span class="text-danger">*</span></span>
<oi-select 
  oi-options="x.id as (x.pregunta.nombre ) for x in preguntas track by x.id"
  ng-model="informe.aspCritico1" 
  placeholder="Seleccione el primer aspecto critico"
  required
  >
</oi-select>
```

El cual es un select que viene precargado con preguntas que tengo en una variable, el sistema funciona perfecto y guarda los datos, el problema esta cuando quiero editar lo que ya esta salvado, la idea es que en el select aparezaca un dato anterior en el caso de que exista.

Si le hago un console.log a la variable informe.aspCritico1 me trae el id pero por alguna razón no me muestra el nombre en el select.

¿Que podría ser?

Gracias!